# php table show data from mysql drop down selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

simply I have two tables: Course_table and Major_table, and they both have relationship entity. I have created a drop down list and linked it to the Major_table, and an html table linked it to the Course_table. What I want to do is display data on the Course_table based on the selection from the drop down list, but when I select something and press 'Filter' it shows an empty table.

Here is my first code:

```
<form method="post" action="staff-page.php">
                            <label for="majorFilter">Select Major: <select id="majorFilter" name="majorFilter">
                            <option value="0">Select a major</option>
                            <?php
                                include ('partials/connectDb.php');

                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM major_table;";
                                $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
                                    $m_id = $row['major_id'];
                                    $m_name = $row['major_name'];

                                    echo "<option value='{$m_id}'>{$m_name}</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                            </select></label>
                            <Button type="button" name="filter" id="filter">Filter</Button>
                        </form>
```

And this is my second code:

```
<table style="height: 400px; width: 600px; overflow: auto; display: none;" id="courseTable">
                            <caption>Course Table</caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Code</th>
                                    <th style="padding-right: 10px;">Cr</th>
                                    <th>Major</th>
                                    <th>Students Enrolled</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <?php
                                error_reporting(0);
                                $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'srs-db') or die('ERROR: Cannot Connect='.mysql_error($conn));


                                $query = "SELECT course_table.course_name, course_table.course_code, course_table.cr, major_table.major_name, course_table.students_enrolled FROM course_table
                                INNER JOIN major_table ON course_table.major = major_table.major_id
                                WHERE course_table.major = '$m_id';";

                                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                                while ($course = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                    # code...
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>.$course[course_name].</td>";
                                    echo "<td>.$course[course_code].</td>";
                                    echo "<td>.$course[cr].</td>";
                                    echo "<td>.$course[major_name].</td>";
                                    echo "<td>.$course[students_enrolled].</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                            ?>

                        </table>
```

Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: do you get any request to the server when you hit the Filter button?

Comment: where is your event? that call the the second code

Comment: @TudorConstantin No, that's why the page doesn't reload I guess. Which is why I am using button type='button'

Comment: @dharmendrachaudhary I'm sorry, but what event you're talking about?

Comment: first of all, make it a input type="submit", so that you'll get your second code executed, like this: <input type="submit" name="filter" id="filter">Filter</input>, then, make sure you'll have the $m_id defined in your second code, then, read about sql injection and how to prevent it :)

Comment: Addition to @TudorConstantin comment, would suggest to use PDO, Prepared Statements as well

Answer (score 0):

In your second code, you need to make your `<tr>` id based and apply a class for all of them. like this:

```
        while ($course = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
              # code...
              echo "<tr class='all_trs' id='display_".$m_id."' style='display:none;'>";
              echo "<td>.$course[course_name].</td>";
              echo "<td>.$course[course_code].</td>";
              echo "<td>.$course[cr].</td>";
              echo "<td>.$course[major_name].</td>";
              echo "<td>.$course[students_enrolled].</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
        }
```

And then you need to place a JQuery [Onchange method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=change) in [Document ready](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=ready):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // will be triggered on Change of your Select box
        $( "#majorFilter" ).change(function() {

          alert("Select Box changed");
          // Hiding all Trs by default.
          $( ".all_trs" ).hide();
          // Showing just the specific TR which is selected in select box
          $( "#display_" + $(this).val() ).show();

        });
    });
</script>
```

> You might notice, that I have used `display:none` for echoing the `<tr>` html, it is because, I'm hiding all the TRs by default and will display only the selected one on Select Box change.

Comment: You might be missing something.. can you post or update your Question with current full code?